# Why I Get NoReverseMatch at Error // Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I could not find the cause of the error.

Urls.py:

```
path('', views.post_list, name="post_list"),
path('<str:url_sistem>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
```

Views.py:

```
def post_detail(request, url_sistem):
url_sistem = Post.objects.get(title)
posts = get_object_or_404(Post, url_sistem=url_sistem)
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'posts':posts})
```

A href link:

```
<a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.url_sistem %}" style="color:black;">
```

Comment: You passed this as `posts` to the template, so it should be `posts.url_sistem`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error that needs to be fixed:

```
def post_detail(request, url_sistem):
    url_sistem = Post.objects.get(title)
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, url_sistem=url_sistem)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'posts':posts})
```

in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post-detail' post.url_sistem %}" style="color:black;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like `<a href="{% url 'projectAppName:post-detail' post.url_sistem %}" style="color:black;">`